# Hammer JS v2.0.4 not recognizing 'panstart' or 'panmove' in Chrome 37.0 only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hammer.js

I wanted to learn Hammer JS by building a simple program to drag an element around the screen, pretty much just like the same on the [Hammer homepage](http://hammerjs.github.io/).

I used the code posted on the Hammer [github page](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/blob/master/tests/manual/visual.html), which seems to be the same code used on the homepage. I was testing the work in Chrome (37.0 / OSX). After working with it for a while and being unable to get the element to move, I opened the same page in Safari and FF. It worked perfectly in both of those browsers.

To pare things down, I added just the required to code to see an event trigger:

```
var mover = document.getElementById("mover");

var mc = new Hammer.Manager(mover);
mc.add(new Hammer.Pan({ threshold: 0, pointers: 0 }));

mc.on("panstart panmove", function(ev) {
  console.log(ev);
});
```

Nothing gets logged in Chrome, but I get proper logging as expected in Safari and FF. I extended the event listener to include 'pan, panend, pancancel, panleft, panright, panup, pandown'. These events WOULD log in Chrome, so it seems like only panstart and panmove were being ignored.

So this code will run on the hammer.js page in Chrome, so clearly Chrome does see the panstart and panmove events in that browser, it's just not happening in my code. Which means somehow I am missing something, despite copying the code over from their site. I checked we were on the same Hammer version, but I am not sure sure what else from here I need to check.

Has anyone else encountered and solved this problem? Or perhaps knows what I am doing wrong to create this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I would create a new issue on the hammer.js repo for this type of error.

Comment: same problem on chrome 38

Comment: I just had a very similar problem (Chrome 43). `panend` was being called but not  start or move, and working in FF. Restarting the browser magically fixed it, but sadly didn’t recover the couple of hours spent debugging!

Answer (score -1):

In the Hammer site say clearly "for better performance on slower devices your should try to keep you callbacks as simple as possible." I think that's the same with Browsers!

Maybe your problem is

```
var mover = document.getElementById("#mover");
```

Why do you type "#mover" instead of "mover"? The "#" sign it's for JQuery and you are using plain javascript. It confuses me that in some browsers this works, so I imagine your ElementID start in fact with the "#"...

Let me know if it helped, please!

Comment: Meh, Sorry. That was a mistype by me. I was targeting the element properly (no '#', verified when I was stepping through the code in DevTools). Not sure where that came from in copying the code into here.